# Difference between "move" and "li" in MIPS assembly language

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I was practicing converting C code into MIPS assembly language, and am having trouble understanding the usage of `move` and `li` in variable assignment.

For example, to implement the following C line in MIPS:

```
int x = 0;
```

If I understand it correctly (I highly doubt this, though), it looks like both of these work in MIPS assembler:

```
move $s0, $zero
li $s0, $zero
```

Am I wrong? What is the difference between these two lines?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `move` instruction copies a value from one register to another. The `li` instruction loads a specific numeric value into that register.

For the *specific* case of zero, you can use either the constant zero or the zero register to get that:

```
move $s0, $zero
li   $s0, 0
```

There's no register that generates a value other than zero, though, so you'd have to use `li` if you wanted some other number, like:

```
li $s0, 12345678
```

Comment: You should also be aware that "move" and "li" are both "pseudo-instructions". "move $s0,$s1" might really be "add $s0,$0,$s1". A "li" instruction might be the combination of a "lui" and a "ori" instruction so "li" may even be two instructions.

Comment: So `li` is conceptually the same as move-immediate?

Answer (score 0):

the `move` instruction moves the value of one register to another while `li` just loads an immediate value to a register.